# Escaping and eliminating spaces from PowerShell scripts to enable roaming of file type associations on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get output similar to this but preferably using `Out-File`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
    <Association Identifier=".html" ProgId="FirefoxHTML" ApplicationName="ChromeHTML" />
</DefaultAssociations>
```

The problem I am having is that with `Write-Host`, extra spaces are being introduced along with the variable values. To use `Out-File` instead, when I try to concatenate each line with something like this:

```
    $Out = $Out + '<Association Identifier="'$($Item.PSParentPath | Split-Path -Leaf)'"'
    Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\test.xml $Out
```

I get an error

> Unexpected token '$(' in expression or statement.

I'm so close to getting the desired output.

If the permissions are changed on `%windir%\system32\OEMDefaultAssociations.xml` to allow standard users to write, a login script can put a copy of what this script outputs into that file so that per user file type associations can roam between Windows 10 computers.

```
$UserChoiceKeys = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\*\UserChoice"
$UserChoiceKeys = $UserChoiceKeys + (Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\*\UserChoice")
Write-Host '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
Write-Host '<DefaultAssociations>'
foreach ($Item in $UserChoiceKeys)
{
Write-Host -NoNewLine '<Association Identifier="'$($Item.PSParentPath | Split-Path -Leaf)'"'
$ProgID = $(Get-ItemProperty $Item.pspath -name "ProgID").ProgID
Write-Host -NoNewLine ' ProgId="'($ProgID)
$ApplicationKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\"+$ProgID+"\Application"
$ApplicationName =  $(Get-ItemProperty $ApplicationKey -name "ApplicationName" -errorAction SilentlyContinue).ApplicationName
Write-Host -NoNewLine '" ApplicationName="'$ApplicationName'" />'
Write-Host ''
}
Write-Host -NoNewline '</DefaultAssociations>'
```

Comment: `Write-Host` can't be used to write to a file (it only writes to the console). I would also recommend to post a short example script that contains only enough code needed to demonstrate your problem. (Make it as easy as possible for other to understand exactly what you are asking.)

Comment: echo test > c:\temp\test.xml
Output redirection allows powershell output to be directed to a file. Sorry I forgot the script on initial posting.

Comment: `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`, not `Write-Host`. If you want to be able to redirect, use `Write-Output`. (And actually, you don't even need to put `Write-Output` specifically, as PowerShell outputs strings.)

Comment: Credit to an internal staff member, this is my solution:  It wont fit here, adding it to initial post.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from OP moved to answer post by editor*

```
$CustomAssociationsFilePath = "$($Env:userprofile)\CustomAssociations.xml" 
$UserChoiceKeys = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\*\UserChoice" 
$UserChoiceKeys += Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\*\UserChoice"
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

$OutputData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + $nl + '<DefaultAssociations>'

foreach ($Item in $UserChoiceKeys) 
{ 
    $OutputData += $nl + '<Association Identifier="' + $($Item.PSParentPath | Split-Path -Leaf) + '"' 
    $ProgID = $(Get-ItemProperty $Item.pspath -name "ProgID").ProgID 
    $OutputData += ' ProgId="' + ($ProgID) 
    $ApplicationKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\" + $ProgID + "\Application" 
    $ApplicationName =  $(Get-ItemProperty $ApplicationKey -name "ApplicationName" -errorAction SilentlyContinue).ApplicationName 
    $OutputData += '" ApplicationName="' + $ApplicationName + '" />' 
} 
$OutputData += $nl + '</DefaultAssociations>'

Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -InputObject $OutputData -FilePath $CustomAssociationsFilePath
```